# Firefox doesn't open links from external sources (e.g. click on link in skype)

Tags: linux, firefox

This happens on both Fedora 20 and Ubuntu 14.04 with XFCE DE. When I click on any link (from external program), a new firefox window is opened with start page. That's all.
I've already checked for launch command - "firefox %u". I have no idea what's the problem and what to do. Help, please.

One more IMPORTANT thing! It also can be fixed just by typing "/usr/bin/firefox" instead of "firefox" in Preferred Applications/

Comment: I'd recommend putting this on Ask Ubuntu rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: but it happens not only on Ubuntu. OK, I'll ask there too

Comment: Yes, but it's likely going to be the same thing either way, as it will probably be something related to either Firefox or XFCE, which is common between both, and you'll find a lot more help with Ubuntu than Fedora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps you with your problem:

[Clicking link doesn't open new tab](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1020580)

Comment: From that link, I found out that only way - downgrade firefox. It lost his convenient menu, but problem is solved now. I'll be waiting hopefully for new version of firefox.